# jQuery - finding an element with multiple HTML tag attributes in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, exception, sizzle

Why using this:

```
var parent = $('div.form.offer_mails');
var period = parent.find('input[type=checkbox,name=timeperiod]');
```

I get this (exception in my Mozilla Firefox Error Console):

```
Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [type=checkbox,name=timeperiod]
```

Isn't it possible to search an element with more than one attribute and it's value?

Please explain and solutionize my problem. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in this way:

```
var period = parent.find('input[type=checkbox][name=timeperiod]');
```

Note that this is also a valid CSS selector.

Comment: Added an answer, but yours is much more correct, thus i deleted mine.

Comment: I will accept your answer in about 11 minutes... thank you alot dog!